# Iterating over 3 same length lists simultaneously

Tags: python

So I tried to do 3 lists simultaneously using zip but it gave me something I didn't want. It game me `U o t` instead of `UH oo t`

```
for (phone, graph, context) in zip(['UH', 'T'], ['oo', ''t], ['t','oo']) 
    tri_tally[(phone, graph, context)] += 1
```

where `tri_tally=defaultdict(int)`

When I tried it game me `{('U', 'o' , 't') : 1}` I want `{('UH', 'oo', 't'):1}`

Comment: Please [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/36979786/edit) you question and modify the contents to be more clear.

Comment: Are `UH`, `oo`, etc. variables? Where are they assigned?

Comment: You haven't pasted your actual code in, because this has a syntax error. Even after fixing it the code does what you expect, not what you told us. We can't help you without code that actually produces the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well

```
for elem in zip(["UH", "T"], ["oo", "t"], ["t", "oo"]):
    print(elem)
```

returns

```
('UH', 'oo', 't')
('T', 't', 'oo')
```

As you expected, so there is something else that is wrong.